# Can't get other files uploaded [python flask] with html

Tags: python, html, flask

The problem is i am able to upload file which are in the same directory as main.py but I am unable to upload other files which are not in the same folder of main.py, suppose - main.py is in c:\users\prabhat\upload\ and the file i am uploading the file is also in c:\users\prabhat\upload\ directory, but if there is file in c:\desktop\B.xlsx then if i upload, then it shows Error, file not found.
how an i resolve this??

index.html code

```
<form class="" action="data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="upload-file" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.form['upload-file']
        return '''
            successfully Done!
            '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't access files uploaded through flask via `request.form` but rather through `request.files`. This should get you a valid file handle:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['upload-file']
```

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/ for more info.

Comment: i am doing some additional task with that file,
and after converting it in request.files it is giving me error-
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage

and the code which gives me error is -
exceldf = pd.read_excel(
            open(file, 'rb'), sheet_name='Sheet1')

Comment: See to the link that I posted for a more complete example. The part you're missing is:
`filename = secure_filename(file.filename)` `file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))`
after which you can do `pd.read_excel(open(filename, 'rb'))` and so on. `file` is not an object of type `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Try file = request.files['upload-file'] instead of request.form, and I guess you want to save it to the server, do it with file.save("path/to/your/folder/filename.extension")

Comment: how will i get that path? because i want to make it live, so, i have to make it generic, so other people can upload and the path automatically get updated. and there is one more thing, i am doing some task also on that excel file, so, if i use files, will i able to do that?